# <div> tag being ignored in IE8 CSS

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I have the following in an ASP XHTML page:

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="searchBlock">
        Last Name:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchLastName" runat="server">p:TextBox>&nbsp;
        First Name:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchFirstName" runat="server </asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Load" runat="server" Text="Load" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="dataBlock">
        Name:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FistName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_MiddleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Suffix" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Save" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

and the corresponding code in the matching CSS sheet:

```
.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

div.searchBlock
{
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #ffc000;
}

div.dataBlock
{
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #80ffff;
}
```

In both Firefox (14) and IE8, as well as the design window in Visual Studio 2010, the form displays as expected; the top ("search" block) background is gold, and the bottom ("dataBlock" block) is a shade of blue.  However, in IE8, while the top is gold, the bottom is white, and also has no padding.

Before anyone says "nested Div tags", note that if the page and search div blocks are removed, the same thing happens - the dataBlock block has a light cyan background and padding in Firefox and VS, but white and no padding in IE8.

In Firefox 14 and the design window in Visual Studio 2010, it works (the DataBlock background is a shade of blue and there is padding around the elements), but in IE8, it doesn't (the DataBlock background is white and there is no padding).

Even if I remove all of the form elements, and change the name of the div from dataBlock to, say, somethingElseBlock, it still does not work properly in IE8.

Comment: Is it just a copy/paste typo in the code above that your CSS class `div.searchBlock` is missing a closing bracket?

Comment: Yes, and it has been corrected, but the problem still exists.

Comment: The doctype tag is:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual outputted html rather than the `asp` code. Also, putting that output html and the css above into a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) as an example of the problem might help us to help you debug the issue.

Comment: "Never Mind" - for whatever reason, even after I made changes, it was getting the page from the cache.  Doing a manual refresh showed the page as intended.

Comment: @DonDelGrande--it might be best for you to just delete this post then.